# Python socket.io connect to socket.io server with authentication handshake

Tags: python, sockets, socket.io

Im having an issue that's related to the python implementation of the socket.io module.

Basically the official javascript documentation of socket.io describes a pre connection authentication handshake that can be send via the client directly when connecting to the server

client.js

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:80', { auth: "sample token" });
```

my issue is that the socket.io documentation for python doesn't describe anything like it

Does anyone have an idea how to do this using the socket.io python module ?

Comment: The docs certainly describe something like it, what specifically is the problem? [Here](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=headers#socketio.Client.connect) is the documentation of all the optional arguments for the connect call, what exactly is missing that you need?

Comment: Im sorry yes that is intact what I need. Feel free to post an answer so I can approve it as a solution